How to cycle tabs in pycharm?
in here:
Make VS Code editor Ctrl+Tab cycle tabs in the same order as they're displayed on screen?
I saw a great way to cycle throw tabs as I do in browser, I see it is possible to do in visual studio code, is it possible to have the same thing in Pycharm?
I do not want to have any window open on ctr+tab as it is right now, I want to cycle throw tabs from fright to left, and back with ctr+shift+tab even in different groups.
It must go throw a way how there are shown, not by the time they where opened.
